Running total that restarts every fiscal year (Oct - Sep)
Example of my desired result:



Date (A)
Value (B)
Fiscal Year running total (C)




01.09.2022
100
100


01.10.2022
200
200


01.11.2022
50
250


01.12.2022
150
400


01.01.2023
125
525


01.02.2023
300
825


01.03.2023
250
1075


01.04.2023
300
1375


01.05.2023
100
1475


01.06.2023
75
1550


01.07.2023
125
1675


01.08.2023
150
1825


01.09.2023
100
1925


01.10.2023
25
25


01.11.2023
300
325


01.12.2023
125
450



I would like to know how I can achieve the 3rd column in this example table, "Fiscal Year running total". Meaning, I'd like to have a running total that resets at the start of every fiscal year. In this case, fiscal years starts in October and ends in September.
Another way of wording it:
I need a way of getting the running total from an unspecific date, to the last time it was a specific date (October).
If it is at all possible, it'd be great to have a formula instead of VB or Power Query solution.
Here is a formula I have come up with, but not found a full solution for yet:
=IF (MONTH (A2) = 10; B2; SUM (OFFSET (INDEX (MATCH (???); 0): A2; 0; 1)) 

"(???)" Being where one would need a formula to find the cell closest to the one we are in that has October in its month and is in the past.
Many thanks in advance!

=IF(MONTH(A2)=10,B2,B2+N(C1))

To be honest, @JvdV answer is a shorter formula but just in case somebody can't use Excel365 here's another approach using SUMPRODUCT:

=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$17<=A2)*--($A$2:$A$17>=IF(MONTH(A2)>=10;DATE(YEAR(A2);10;1);DATE(YEAR(A2)-1;10;1)))*--($A$2:$A$17<=IF(MONTH(A2)>=10;DATE(YEAR(A2)+1;9;30);DATE(YEAR(A2);9;30)))*$B$2:$B$17)

Notice this formula will work only if dates in column A are real dates (numeric) and not text dates.

While JvdV's solution is shorter, this version not only works in non 365 versions, it's also usable in tables. Thank you for taking the time to think up an alternative!

Here is one way, assuming monthly figures and your input is in order as per given sample data:

Formula in C2:
=MAP(A2:A17,B2:B17,LAMBDA(d,v,SUM(XLOOKUP(10,MONTH(A2:d),B2:v,v,,-1):v)))

or, as per your comment, apply this in a table:
=LET(v,[@[Value (B)]],SUM(XLOOKUP(10,MONTH(INDEX([Date (A)],1):[@[Date (A)]]),INDEX([Value (B)],1):v,v,,-1):v))


This is an amazing and elegant solution, thank you! One thing to note though is that using this formula in a table will result in a #SPILL! error.

@InfiniteFox the formula is simple given by JvdV Sir, you can apply similar logic in Structured References as well --> =SUM(XLOOKUP(10,MONTH(A$2:A2),B$2:B2,B$2:B2,,-1):B2)

@InfiniteFox, thanks for the compliments. I have edited the answer to include the syntax you'd use when you want to apply this in a table. Though the accepted solution also is a fine one which also works in older versions of Excel.

A shorter pre-365 formula:-

=SUM(INDEX([Value (B)],MAX(3+12*INT((ROW()-3)/12),2)-1):[@[Value (B)]])

rendered slightly more legible when the underlying data are not in a table, i.e.
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,MAX(3+12*INT((ROW()-3)/12),2)):B2)

